# Rpi not booting after install (green led 8 blinks)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I've just installed Windows IoT in a Rpi 3. First time boot everything is ok, after that if I reebot or shutdown a boot it doesn't boot anymore :(

It shows the loading screen for few seconds but after showing the display screen window (that with the colours) it doesn't boot, the only thing is that the green led is blinking 8 times.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your power supply source. Make sure it is  5V - 2A.

Answer (score 0):

Tori,

I'm having the same problem with one of my devices. The issue is addressed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70c2b5ab-9e49-4ec2-961f-c196e85ef5a8/raspberry-pi-3-and-14322-iotuapoobe-stuck-on-welcome-pi3-wifi-issue?forum=WindowsIoT

I'm currently downloading the new image (14366) which might fix the issue.

Are you running an old image or have you already installed the new one? I suggest to re-flash your SD card with 14366 and try again.

Best regards
-Simon

Answer (score 0):

Check that your microSD card is a class 10 which Windows 10 IoT requires.  Also, some cards may not be fully compatible and have issues.  A list of verified cards can be found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm#Storage